# Short story where a little child lies that the family robot hit her and mother calls the company

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story somewhere between 2002 - 2010, but I remember the book I read it from was very old and tattered, so I think it was likely quite old when I read it.

The child asks the robot to give it milk and play chess at the same time, but the robot is designed for single tasks only. Then the child cries and tells her mom that the robot hit her. When the mom calls to complain, the support person tells her about the three laws of robotics, and why it's impossible that the robot hit her. The support guy offers some other robot and the story ends there.

Comment: Do you remember how long ago a long time ago is? Was it new then? Do you know anything else about this story? Any other plot elements, character descriptions, the outcome of the story? And if this is a short story can you add the `[short-stories]` tag? It helps catalogue questions.

Comment: This is basically the entire story I think. The support guy offers some other robot and the story ends there. Not much else I can remember. I don't remember exactly when I read it, but I sort of remember the book from which I read it being old and tattered, so I don't think the year I read it matters.

Comment: Years matter because it helps track down the story, searching by date periods is very helpful. You can [edit] this into the question.

Comment: The _Three Laws of Robotics_? Do you remember if it was an Asimov story? (It does sound very Asimovy).

Comment: Could be, but I don't remember. I tried searching on google with keywords like "Isaac Asimov child robot milk chess" but didn't get a good result

Comment: It is similar to [_Robbie_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbie_(short_story)) by Asimov but doesn't match most of your description.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I looked at it. It looks similar. Maybe the one I read was inspired by it or something? I definitely remember  the main part of the story was the support guy explaining the 3 laws of robotics

Comment: @ColonD To be honest I didn't think that was actually the story you was describing. It is, however, close enough that I thought it was worth mentioning in the comments just in case you have got two stories mixed up or something like that.